# dropdown list always sets modelstate invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Whats wrong with this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Post.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "CategoryName"), "-- Please select --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Post.CategoryId)
```

When I submit the form the modelstate is invalid and this dropdown list gets flagged as an error, even though i select a value from the dropdown list.

(btw CategoryId is an FK in my Post Table)
I haved added this "buddy" class as a partial

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Post_Validation))]
public partial class Post
{

}

class Post_Validation
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

}
```

controller:

```
// GET: /News/Add
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            var model = new AddPostViewModel() { Categories = categoryRepository.GetAllCategories(), Post = new Post(), IsEditMode=false };
            return View(model);
        }


            //
            // POST: /News/Add
            [Authorize]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Add(AddPostViewModel model)
            {
              if (!ModelState.IsValid)
              {
              ..etc
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this particular code you have posted. What might be wrong is the model you are expecting in the controller action which is being posted to. For example if this model is not the same as the model used to render this view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Post post) { ... }
```

instead of:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ModelContainingPostConmtainingCategoryId post) { ... }
```

The name of the dropdownlist generated will be the following: `name="Post.CategoryId"` and if your controller action doesn't take a model having a property called `Post` with a property called `CategoryId` and this `CategoryId` property is marked with `Required` you will get the behavior you are describing.

Other possible reasons is that you have additional properties which are required and which you haven't included in your request. The way to find this out is to analyze the model you are getting back in your controller action and see what's missing. Also looking at the `ModelState` property itself in debug mode will tell you which properties have validation errors.

---

UPDATE:

Here's a full working example that could be used as base:

Model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Post_Validation))]
public class Post
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

class Post_Validation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class AddPostViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new AddPostViewModel()
        {
            Categories = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ToString(),
                Text = "category " + x
            }),
            Post = new Post()
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(AddPostViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model AppName.Models.AddPostViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Post.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"), "-- Please select --")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Post.CategoryId)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: The model appears fine and when i remove the validationfor on the category DDL it submits okay. CategoryId is an int...could that be an issue?

Comment: @raklos, it could if you are using non-integers as values for your dropdown. Also it would happen only with nullable integers. If you are using non-nullable integer you will get an exception in this case. Is `CategoryId` assigned a value inside the controller action you are posting to?

Comment: CategoryId is coming back as null.. ID's are all int, and viewing the source value for each option in the select is an integer too

Comment: @raklos, if `CategoryId` is defined as `int` it cannot be null. Integers are value types and value types cannot be `null`. They have a default value and for integers this default value is `0`. So the problem is as I suspected: your binding doesn't work correctly: the selected value in the dropdown is not properly bound to the value in the controller action. Of course without showing your code I cannot help you any further as I don't know how your model look like neither the controller action you are posting to.

Comment: @raklos, I can see your update with the model. You forgot to post how does your controller action look like.

Comment: just added the partial im adding the validation attribute to. if i take this out and add it to the ViewModel instead then it works fine!...which is odd, i prefer to add the validation in the buddy class if possible

Comment: @raklos, how about the controller action?

Comment: @raklos, your code looks fine. Can't see anything wrong with it and I am unable to reproduce the behavior you are describing. I will update my answer with a full working example you could use as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Your model state will always be invalid for your dropdowns if your selected variable type is not a string.